# can't run a scala script on Mac OS X

Tags: scala, macos

Running a scala script on Mac OS X results in the following error:

> Unable to establish connection to
>   compilation daemon

I found a page reporting the same problem:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576568

To solve the problem, the page said:

> Can you please tell what does
>   /etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf contain?
>
> If the value is 1, can you try to:
>
> 1) sudo sed -i 's/net.ipv6.bindv6only\
>   =\ 1/net.ipv6.bindv6only\ =\ 0/' \ /etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf && sudo
>   invoke-rc.d procps restart
>
> 2) Then, run scala/fsc as usual and
>   see if the bug is still there.

But I can't find a bindv6only.conf in my Mac OS X.
How can I solve the problem?

-- System Information:

Scala version 2.7.7.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_20)

Mac OS X 10.6.3

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the Java property `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` to disable Java's IPv6 ?

For more details see [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html).

Comment: I tried a following line and got the same the problem again, ummm:

scala -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true HelloWorld.scala

Comment: @wataradio On Scala 2.7.x, `scala -D...` doesn't really work. Use `JAVA_OPTS` instead.

Comment: I tried JAVA_OPTS in .bashrc like this: export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true". But the same problem occured again.

Comment: I have found another page reporting the same problem(http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Unable-to-establish-connection-to-compilation-daemon-td1999193.html). The page reported it was specific to Mac OS X. But I couldn't find a solution in the page.

Comment: I tried this guide "The Fast Scala Compiler and the OS X Firewall" (http://www.scala-lang.org/node/294), and confirmed it doesn't work.